# WinServer2008R2 Task Scheduler - Define unique Argument in Action for only one Trigger

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a windows console app that's launched via Task Scheduler (multiple triggers: 6am and 1pm). The Action for each starts a program.

I want to add a 3rd trigger at some arbitrary time of day (e.g. 5am) but for this execution **only** I want to add in **one argument** via **Edit Action**. When I do this, the argument is provided to each trigger.

The dialog does not seem to support this requirement. Is there some way to accomplish this via Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

I conclude the Task Scheduler does NOT support the above requirement. The solution, however, is embarrassingly simple. I just created a new folder and then created a new task with the desired time and arguments. Duh!!